# How to use actuators to control a free joint in mujoco_py?

Tags: python, mujoco

I am using mujoco_py to build a simulation for a hand. I have some some floating fingers that I want to control using actuators. How do I control a free joint that has 7 DOF (x,y,z, rotation quaternion) with acuators?

Thanks for the help!